# Centering nav within main container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center nav tag within the main-container div, but it seems to have a bit too much space on the right. I tried margin: 0 auto method as well as display: inline/inline-block and text-align on the child element - but it does not work.

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

.main-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fff;
}

.main-container nav {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.main-container nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.main-container nav ul li {
  width: 48%; 
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto auto 10px 10px;
}

.main-container nav ul li.one {
  background: url('http://media.npr.org/images/picture-show-flickr-promo.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

 a span {
   position: relative;
   top: 40%;
   font-size: 2em;
   z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
 <div class="main-container">
      <nav>
        <ul>
       <li class="fruits"><a href="one.html"><span> One </span></a></li>
       <li class="vegetables"><a href="two.html"><span> Two </span></a></li>
       <li class="carbohydrates"><a href="three.html"><span> Three </span></a></li>
       <li class="proteins"><a href="four.html"><span> Four </span></a></li>
       <li class="junk-food"><a href="five.html"><span> Five </span></a></li>
       <li class="health-tips"><a href="six.html"><span> Six </span></a></li>  
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hi now used to this**

```
.main-container nav ul{padding:0;}
```

or used to always css **[reset](http://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/)**

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9f66wef7/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

The problem:
`ul` element has `padding` and `margin` by default. You have to set those property to 0.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f007o9L1/1/)

```
 .main-container nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```